# Create a pivot table with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have a table in Postgres called `listings` that looks like this:

| id | neighborhood | bedrooms | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | downtown | 0 | 189000 |
| 2 | downtown | 3 | 450000 |
| 3 | riverview | 1 | 300000 |
| 4 | riverview | 0 | 250000 |
| 5 | downtown | 1 | 325000 |
| 6 | riverview | 2 | 350000 |

etc.

How do I write a crosstab query that shows the average price per bedrooms as the columns and neighborhoods as the rows?

The output of the query should have the following format:

| neighborhood | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| downtown | 189000 | 325000 | - | 450000 |
| riverview | 250000 | 300000 | 350000 | - |

etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First compute the average with the aggregate function [`avg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```sql
SELECT neighborhood, bedrooms, avg(price)
FROM   listings
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Then feed the result to the `crosstab()` function (provided by the additional module [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html)). Cast the avg to `int` if you want rounded results as displayed:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT neighborhood, bedrooms, avg(price)::int
    FROM   listings
    GROUP  BY 1, 2
    ORDER  BY 1, 2;'

  , $$SELECT unnest('{0,1,2,3}'::int[])$$
   ) AS ct ("neighborhood" text, "0" int, "1" int, "2" int, "3" int);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0rdBs6pm)

Detailed instructions:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

The same can be achieved with the aggregate `FILTER` clause. A bit simpler, and doesn't need an additional module, but typically slower. Related answer with side-by-side solutions:

- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)

Comment: @Avishai: (Fully functional) syntax shorthand with positional references, short for `GROUP  BY neighborhood, bedrooms`

Answer (score 25):

Another solution that implement with filter:

```
SELECT neighborhood,
   avg(price) FILTER (WHERE bedrooms = 0) AS "0",
   avg(price) FILTER (WHERE bedrooms = 1) AS "1",
   avg(price) FILTER (WHERE bedrooms = 2) AS "2",
   avg(price) FILTER (WHERE bedrooms = 3) AS "3"
FROM listings
GROUP BY neighborhood;
```

Answer (score 19):

The best way to build pivot tables in Postgres are CASE expressions.

```sql
SELECT neighborhood,
       round(avg((CASE WHEN bedrooms = 0 THEN price END)), 2) AS "0",
       round(avg((CASE WHEN bedrooms = 1 THEN price END)), 2) AS "1",
       round(avg((CASE WHEN bedrooms = 2 THEN price END)), 2) AS "2",
       round(avg((CASE WHEN bedrooms = 3 THEN price END)), 2) AS "3"
FROM listings
GROUP BY neighborhood;
```

Running this on the question data yields

```
NEIGHBORHOOD                  0          1          2          3
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
downtown                 256888     334000       NULL       NULL
riverview                  NULL     505000       NULL       NULL
```

Comment: This particular example of using case statements is incorrect. The statement `round(avg((case when bedroom = 0 then price else 0 end)),2)` means that every apartment with more than 0 bedrooms gets treated as a 0 bedroom with price 0 when taking the average.

Comment: Look, I did a similar approach here for my transposed/pivoted query using your approach.

If I *DONT* add the `avg` function (lets say for `bedroom` in this case) Postgres will complain and say that `bedroom` would need to be grouped by as well in combination with `neighborhood`. 

Do you have any idea why `avg` removes the additional group by ?

Comment: @Evan Allen, I agree that this is often simple when you have a set amount of columns to pivot on. I think your query can be a lot simpler however, consider changing it to `CASE WHEN bedrom = 0 THEN price END`,  same as `CASE .... ELSE NULL END` so the aggregate function would ignore those. I would suggest an edit but queue is full