# For loop inside SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table named watersourcetype consisting of water types.

link : [watersourcetype TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uES6g.png)

and another table health_and_sanitation consisting of household no. and watersource_id
I have this query :

```
SELECT h.purok_number,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Community water system-own' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Community water system-shared' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Deep well-own' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Deep well-shared' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Artesian well-own' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS e,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Artesian well-shared' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS f,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Dug/shallow well-own' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS g,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Dug/shallow well-shared' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS h,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'River, stream, lake, spring, bodies of water' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS i,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Bottled water' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS j,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = 'Tanker truck/Peddler' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS k
FROM health_and_sanitation AS hs, house_hold AS h, f_member as f 
WHERE
     h.brgy_name='$brgy_name' AND 
     h.hh_number=hs.hh_number AND 
     h.hh_number=f.hh_number AND
     f.is_household='HOUSEHOLD' AND 
     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM f.reg_date) BETWEEN '$sel_year' AND '$sel_year' 
group by h.purok_number 
order by h.purok_number
```

what i want is to put a for loop inside above sql query since table watersourcetype is dynamic another data will be added to watersourcetype soon so i dont have to define in my case statement on above query the watersystem . The query should look like this :

```
$qry = pg_query("select cwatertype from tbl_watersourcetype");
```

SQL:

```
SELECT h.purok_number, 
           // is this possible ? putting a while loop or forloop inside a query in PHP ?
          while($row = pg_fetch_array($qry)) 
          {
           SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = '$row['cwatertype']' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a 
          }
FROM health_and_sanitation AS hs, house_hold AS h, f_member as f 
WHERE
    h.brgy_name='$brgy_name' AND 
    h.hh_number=hs.hh_number AND 
    h.hh_number=f.hh_number AND
    f.is_household='HOUSEHOLD' AND 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM f.reg_date) BETWEEN '$sel_year' AND '$sel_year' 
group by h.purok_number 
order by h.purok_number
```

is that possible ?

Comment: don't build your own pivot tables... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgres-sql

Comment: Post the all the tables' structures and sample data. `\d health_and_sanitation`

Comment: is it possible to put while statment inside a query if it is, then how ?                                                            $qry = pg_query("select cwatertype from tbl_watersourcetype");    $sql = "SELECT h.purok_number, ";
          while($row = pg_fetch_array($qry)) 
          {
           SUM(CASE WHEN hs.watersystem = '$row['cwatertype']' THEN          1 ELSE 0 END) AS a 
          }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example on how to put for loop inside SELECT statement :

```
$qry_6_12 .= "  SELECT count(ncropfarmingreasonid) as counted , " ;

     for($i=2;$i<=$count_row;$i++) // loop the number of rows and used $i as ncropfarmingreasonid 
          {           
            if(($count_row-$i)==0)
              {
                 $qry_6_12 .= "SUM(CASE WHEN ncropfarmingreasonid = ".$i." THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END) a".$i."";
              }  
            else 
              {
                 $qry_6_12 .= "SUM(CASE WHEN ncropfarmingreasonid = ".$i." THEN 1  
                 ELSE 0 END) a".$i.",";                                  
              }        
          }
      $qry_6_12 .= " FROM tbl_climatechange as c, tbl_household as h, tbl_barangay as b where h.chholdnumber=c.chholdnumber and b.cbrgycode=h.cbrgycode and b.cbrgyname = 'AMPAYON' ";
      $query_6_12 = pg_query($qry_6_12);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your query correctly, you are trying to retrieve the number of watersourcetypes per household, with a single record returned per household. If that is indeed the case you need to use the `crosstab()` function from the `tablefunc` extension.

However, if you can get by with multiple rows giving the number of sources per watersourcetype per household then you can simply and more efficiently use the `COUNT()` aggregate in the `SELECT` statement (with some *decent* formatting for legibility):

```
SELECT h.purok_number, hs.watersystem, COUNT(hs.watersystem) AS num
   FROM health_and_sanitation AS hs,
        house_hold AS h,
        f_member AS f
   WHERE h.brgy_name='$brgy_name'
     AND h.hh_number=hs.hh_number
     AND h.hh_number=f.hh_number
     AND f.is_household='HOUSEHOLD'
     AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM f.reg_date) BETWEEN '$sel_year' AND '$sel_year'
   GROUP BY h.purok_number, hs.watersystem
   ORDER BY h.purok_number;
```

Additionally, I am assuming that your `health_and_sanitation` table is a view on the `watersourcetype` table; otherwise you are duplicating data in two tables which is (generally) a big boo-boo. Given also your issue with additional water source type, you may want to see if your database design is in [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3NF).

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: not what I want sir, what i want is to put a loop inside a select query statement based on another table value. But thanks for the answer by the way :)

Comment: @daR: I beg to differ about what you want. You want to solve a query problem. You _think_ you need a loop inside a query statement, but you can't have it. It doesn't exist. So find another solution. If you insist that you want a loop inside a select query then I suggest you hack the source code to make it so ;-) The only thing that would approximate what you want is to use the EXECUTE command inside of a function to parse together a very ugly and inefficient query to do something that could be done in other ways with far less effort and at higher speed and efficiency.