# SQL query : transform rows to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Here's an example of my table.

[image]

I need to do a query that shows those IDs who have 0 as a fee on one of two months (11 or 12) or both.

So from the example, I need to show ID 1,3,4 but not 2, like on the screenshot below.

[image]

I tried the query below:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.month, t1.fee, t2.id, t2.month, t2.fee
FROM
    table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.month = '11'
  AND t2.month = '12'
  AND (t1.fee = 0 OR t2.fee = 0);
```

But with this query, I only see ID 1,3 but not ID 4. I guess it's because of `t1.id = t2.id` but no idea how to do otherwise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql might help.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql ansi compliant query

```sql
    SELECT id, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 11 THEN MONTH ELSE NULL END) AS month11, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 11 THEN fee ELSE NULL END) AS fee11, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 12 THEN MONTH ELSE NULL END) AS month12, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 12 THEN fee ELSE NULL END ) AS fee12
    FROM t
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING ( MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 11 THEN fee ELSE NULL END) = 0 OR MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 12 THEN fee ELSE NULL END ) = 0 )
    ORDER BY id
```

Comment: however, I wonder if there's a way to do it using "outer join" instead of "max(case...)", do you have an idea ?

Comment: It would be a full outer join then, you may have an id with the month 12 without any row with the month 11 for the corresponding id. Also, it would mean scanning the table t twice. 

`sql
SELECT COALESCE( t11.id, t12.id ) AS id,
 t11.month AS month11,
 t11.fee AS fee11,
 t12.month AS month12,
 t12.fee AS fee12
FROM (SELECT * FROM t WHERE MONTH = 11 ) AS t11
FULL OUTER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM t WHERE MONTH = 12 ) AS t12 ON t11.id = t12.id
WHERE ( t11.fee = 0 OR t12.fee = 0 )
`

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, this can make use of the `filter` syntax:

```
SELECT t.id,
       11 as month,
       MAX(t.fee) FILTER (WHERE t.month = 11) as fee_11, 
       12 as month,
       MAX(t.fee) FILTER (WHERE t.month = 12) as fee_12
FROM t
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING MAX(t.fee) FILTER (WHERE t.month = 11) = 0 OR
       MAX(t.fee) FILTER (WHERE t.month = 12) = 0;
```

Note:  The two month columns are redundant.

Comment: hi, I just tried your query and it doesn't understand fee_11 / fee_12 of the last line. do you have an idea why ?

Comment: @ayay . . . I just forget that Postgres doesn't support column aliases in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 2):

you need conditional aggregation

```
  select id,month,max(case when month=11 then fee end) fee11,
     max(case when month=12 then fee end) as fee12
    from (
    select * from table t1
    where t1.id in ( select id from table where fee=0)
    ) a group by id,month
```

Comment: Hi, your query worked out but it doesn't give what exactly I want. for example, ID 3 and 1 are appeared 2 times...