# How to avoid sub queries while joining tables?

Tags: postgresql

-- I am extra newbie here and feel this is either trivial or wrong database modelling --

In the below case:

```
create TABLE objects (
id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
name text unique
);

create TABLE features (
id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
name text
);

create TABLE features_map (
id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
o_id BIGINT REFERENCES objects ON DELETE restrict,
f_id BIGINT REFERENCES features ON DELETE restrict,
value text
);

insert into features(id, name) values 
(1, 'length'), 
(2, 'wheels'); 

insert into objects(id, name) values 
(1, 'car'), 
(2, 'bike'); 

insert into features_map(o_id,f_id,value) values
(1,1,'4.5m'),
(1,2,'4'),
(2,1,'2.3m'),
(2,2,'2');
```

I would like to get this desired output, i.e. left joining but merging results on a single row with different columns:

```
select o.id, o.name, 
(select value from features_map fm join features f on fm.f_id=f.id where fm.o_id=o.id and f.name='length') as length, 
(select value from features_map fm join features f on fm.f_id=f.id where fm.o_id=o.id and f.name='wheels') as wheels
from objects o;

id|name|length|wheels|
--|----|------|------|
 1|car |4.5m  |4     |
 2|bike|2.3m  |2     |
```

This type of query gets too slow with increasing size of tables e.g. objects count>10000 and features_map count>40000.

Using a `join` the query stays quite fast, but results appear (obviously) on multiple lines:

```
select *
from objects o
join features_map fm on o.id=fm.o_id
join features f on f.id=fm.f_id;

id|name|id|o_id|f_id|value|id|name  |
--|----|--|----|----|-----|--|------|
 1|car | 1|   1|   1|4.5m | 1|length|
 1|car | 2|   1|   2|4    | 2|wheels|
 2|bike| 3|   2|   1|2.3m | 1|length|
 2|bike| 4|   2|   2|2    | 2|wheels|
```

How can I get the desired output with the speed of the `join` approach?

Ciao,
aaWnSd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a pivot table with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql)

Comment: Hi, not sure this solves. Too complicated for me to understand and validate. Thank you anyhow for your help!

Comment: I know isn't that easy the first time you looks at it., but give it a try because that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e31c249cd5458d98b576a14906b19249)

You need a pivot table. This can be achieved by grouping your data set and then aggregate with filtered values.

In this case the `MIN()` function has been used, but it doesn't matter. You could use `MAX()` or `SUM()` as well because you only have just one value. So the `MIN()` of one single value == `MAX()` of this values == `SUM()` ...

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.name,
    MIN(value) FILTER (WHERE f.name = 'length') AS length,
    MIN(value) FILTER (WHERE f.name = 'wheels') AS wheels
FROM objects o
JOIN features_map fm ON o.id=fm.o_id
JOIN features f ON f.id=fm.f_id
GROUP BY o.id, o.name
ORDER BY o.id
```