# Change column values to column headers in Postgres SQL replacing with values from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, common-table-expression

I am unable to figure out how to make a column values into column headers and assign appropriate values as it happens

Say I have a Postgres database with the following table:

```
 Name      Subject       Score      Region
=======   =========     =======     =======
 Joe       Chemistry      20        America 
 Robert    Math           30        Europe
 Jason     Physics        50        Europe
 Joe       Math           70        America
 Robert    Physics        80        Europe
 Jason     Math           40        Europe
 Jason     Chemistry      60        Europe
```

I want to select/fetch data in the following form:

```
 Name      Chemistry     Math       Physics     Region
=======   ==========    =======    ========    ========
 Joe        20            70         null       America
 Robert     null          30         80         Europe
 Jason      60            40         50         Europe
```

Considering that there are 80 subjects. How do I write an SQL select statement that returns data in this format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20618487/11878472 check this solution

Comment: Are the list of subjects limited to the 3 mentioned there?

Comment: No the list of subjects are actually 80

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I recommend using the `FILTER` syntax for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name,
       MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE subject = 'Chemistry') AS Chemistry,
       MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE subject = 'Math') AS Math,
       MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE subject = 'Physics') AS Physics
FROM grades
GROUP BY name
```