# PostgreSQL - Group By Two Columns And Use One As Column For Result

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have two tables: `Subject` and `Journal` as following:

```
Subject
 id | name
----------
  1 | fruit
  2 | drink
  3 | vege
  4 | fish
```

and

```
Journal
 id | subj | reference | value
------------------------------
  1 |    1 |       foo |    30
  2 |    2 |       bar |    20
  3 |    1 |       bar |    35
  4 |    1 |       bar |    10
  5 |    2 |       baz |    25
  6 |    4 |       foo |    30
  7 |    4 |       bar |    40
  8 |    1 |       baz |    20
  9 |    2 |       bar |     5
```

I want to sum `Journal.value` group by both `subj` and `reference`.

I know the `group by` clause is for this purpose, but I would expect an output as following:

```
reference | subj_1 | subj_2 | subj_3 | subj_4
          |  fruit |  drink |   vege |   fish (even better)
---------------------------------------------
      foo |     30 |        |        |     30
      bar |     45 |     25 |        |     40
      baz |     20 |     25 |        |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql Thing you are looking for called "pivot table".

Comment: [Crosstab or pivot questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: Many thanks to Mikhail Aksenov and a_horse_with_no_name! That's exactly what  I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a Sql Statement based on the current data.

Then use that generated Sql statement

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table Subject (
>  id serial primary key, 
>  name varchar(30) not null
>  );
>
> insert into Subject (id, name) values
>  (1 ,'fruit')
> ,(2 ,'drink')
> ,(3 ,'vege')
> ,(4 ,'fish');
>  
> create table Journal (
>  id int, 
>  subj int, 
>  reference varchar(30), 
>  value int
> );
>
> insert into Journal   
> (id, subj, reference, value) values
>  (1, 1, 'foo', 30)
> ,(2, 2, 'bar', 20)
> ,(3, 1, 'bar', 35)
> ,(4, 1, 'bar' ,10)
> ,(5, 2, 'baz', 25)
> ,(6, 4, 'foo', 30)
> ,(7, 4, 'bar', 40)
> ,(8, 1, 'baz', 20)
> ,(9, 2, 'bar', 5);
> ```

**Generate statement:**

> ```
> SELECT $f$SELECT * FROM crosstab(
>      $$SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
>        j.reference, 'subj_'||j.subj||'_'||s.name AS data_type, SUM(j.value) AS val
>        FROM Journal j
>        JOIN Subject s ON s.id = j.subj
>        GROUP BY j.reference, j.subj, s.name
>        ORDER BY j.reference$$
>
>     ,$$VALUES ($f$     || string_agg(quote_literal(data_type), '), (') || $f$)$$)
> AS x (reference text, $f$ || string_agg(quote_ident(data_type), ' int, ') || ' int)'
> AS Stmt
> FROM  (SELECT concat('subj_', id, '_', name) AS data_type FROM Subject) x
> ```

> ```
> | stmt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SELECT * FROM crosstab(<br>     $$SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)<br>       j.reference, 'subj_'||j.subj||'_'||s.name AS data_type, SUM(j.value) AS val<br>       FROM Journal j<br>       JOIN Subject s ON s.id = j.subj<br>       GROUP BY j.reference, j.subj, s.name<br>       ORDER BY j.reference$$<br><br>    ,$$VALUES ('subj_1_fruit'), ('subj_2_drink'), ('subj_3_vege'), ('subj_4_fish')$$)<br>AS x (reference text, subj_1_fruit int, subj_2_drink int, subj_3_vege int, subj_4_fish int) |
> ```

**Run it**

> ```
> SELECT * FROM crosstab(
>      $$SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
>        j.reference, 'subj_'||j.subj||'_'||s.name AS data_type, SUM(j.value) AS val
>        FROM Journal j
>        JOIN Subject s ON s.id = j.subj
>        GROUP BY j.reference, j.subj, s.name
>        ORDER BY j.reference$$
>
>     ,$$VALUES ('subj_1_fruit'), ('subj_2_drink'), ('subj_3_vege'), ('subj_4_fish')$$)
> AS x (reference text, subj_1_fruit int, subj_2_drink int, subj_3_vege int, subj_4_fish int)
> ```

> ```
> reference | subj_1_fruit | subj_2_drink | subj_3_vege | subj_4_fish
> :-------- | -----------: | -----------: | ----------: | ----------:
> bar       |           45 |           25 |        null |          40
> baz       |           20 |           25 |        null |        null
> foo       |           30 |         null |        null |          30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f4336c0d473e2d06ec5098efcd0cfbe6)*

Answer (score 0):

This produces your desired result:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT reference, subj, sum(value)
    FROM   journal
    GROUP  BY 1, 2
    ORDER  BY 1, 2'

  , $$VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)$$
   ) AS ct (reference text, fruit int, drink int, vege int, fish int);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=19240b37564bf625dc18773244a8e714)*

Except for the sort order, which seems arbitrary?

Detailed explanation and instructions:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)