# splitting jsonb columns to a new column within a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table by the name food_order in POSTGRESQL, this table contains 3 columns i.e. `_id`, status, and `status_events`. Status_events contains a JSON string like below

| _id. | status. | . status_events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Order_delivered | [{""status_name"":""order_received"", |

```
                            ""status_time"":    
                            1632580815}, {""status_name"": 
                             ""order_accepted"", ""status_time"": 
                            1632580880},
```

I want to split the status_events like below

| _id | status. | status_name_1 | status_time1 | status_name_2 | status_time_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | order_delivered | order_received | 1634567 | order_accepted | 16543255 |

I tried the below option, but getting each status in a separate row
`SELECT arr.item_object,arr.item_object->>'status_name'as status, arr.item_object->>'status_time'as stime FROM food_order, jsonb_array_elements(status_events) with ordinality arr(item_object, position)` ;

Comment: Does the array always contain exactly two objects?

Comment: You already did the hard part, you only need to [pivot values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql), in this case you can use `position`: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wVG37Dr0).